# Soundcloud API: Retrieving tracks that are not in sets

Tags: soundcloud

I am looking for a way to retrieve tracks that don't belong to any sets of tracks.
The idea is that I would retrieve separate tracks by hitting
'/users/{id}/tracks', and then I would also retrieve sets (and the tracks that belong to sets)
by hitting '/users/{id}/playlists'

As of now I could only come up with a solution like:
1. Retrieve sets of tracks per user
2. Retrieve all tracks per user and remove tracks that are returned by 1.

Please consult if there exists a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but there's no simpler way to do this.